# Python program to load only a certain mega bytes of an excel file into the dataframe and convert it to string

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am pretty new to Python and I was going through some of the uses of the `pandas` library. However, I could not find a way to load only a partial excel file into the memory and play with it. For example, if I set the memory limit as 1MB, the program should be able to read the first 1MB from the excel file of a size larger than 1MB.

From the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747476/in-pandas-whats-the-equivalent-of-nrows-from-read-csv-to-be-used-in-read-ex), I see an option to load a certain number of rows. But I  would not know the number of rows in the input file. Also, I do not know how many bytes of data has been read by this code.

Is there a way to load the number of rows in an iterative way where in the number of bytes read can also be calculated in each iteration and can be cumulatively summed up?

Answer (score 1):

## 1.) conversion factor

"Taste" some example data near the head of the worksheet,
compute an average of how many bytes per row,
then use that to predict how many rows fit in your memory budget.

## 2.) polars

The [polars](https://pypi.org/project/polars) project
has a heavy emphasis on "use less RAM!" and on rapid I/O.
A convenient `.to_pandas()` method makes it trivially easy
to convert a polars DataFrame to your favorite format.
Consider doing the filtering in polars and handing off
the result to pandas, formatted as the rest of your
app expects it.

## 3.) generator

For CSV this is easy, and definitely won't do extra malloc's.
For other formats we might do an allocation for the entire sheet,
but then we can definitely avoid Pandas allocations for unwanted rows.

We will use a [dict reader](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl-dictreader),
plus a generator for early termination.

```
from sys import getsizeof
import openpyxl_dictreader

df = pd.DataFrame(read_initial(1_000_000, filespec, sheet))

def read_initial(budget: int, filespec: Path, sheet: str):
    size = 0
    reader = openpyxl_dictreader.DictReader(filespec, sheet, read_only=True, data_only=True)
    for row in reader:
        size += (sum(map(getsizeof, row.values()))
               + sum(map(getsizeof, row.keys())))
        if size > budget:
            break
        yield row
```

Feel free to use a fancier cost estimate,
if accuracy of recursive `getsizeof` isn't to your liking.

Consider converting *.xlsx files to a more stream-friendly format like .csv.

We prefer the
[read_only=True](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31189961)
keyword arg so we only consume constant memory despite large file size.

If you're unable to evaluate formulas and essentially wished
the Excel file was a CSV file, then supply a
[data_only=True](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook)
kwarg.

Comment: do you know if this line of code `reader = openpyxl_dictreader.DictReader(filespec, sheet)` loads the entire file into the memory?

Comment: got your point about early pruning of the rows, but my doubt was more on loading the file initially which is  `reader = openpyxl_dictreader.DictReader(filespec, sheet)`. Would this not load the entire sheet into the memory?

Comment: You can choose to load the entire sheet into memory if you wish. Or you can go with the recommended `read_only=True` setting, which uses a fixed buffer allocation, independent of file size.

Comment: Got it, thanks @J_H. May I know what is the default buffer allocation size and also if there is a way to change it?

Comment: Show us your memory measurements. What RAM constraint do you run within, and under different conditions what allocated amounts are recorded by your benchmark code?

Comment: as I mentioned, I am new to python and I have not written any benchmark code for this yet, but I run with a mere 2GB RAM and that is where memory if of primary concern for us. I will research on how to write the benchmark coding in python and try to do so

Comment: tried this and I observed that it is printing the underlying cell formula rather than the cell value. May I know how to get the cell value for the formula based cells?

Comment: You don't _have_ to learn how to read [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook). But you may find it a valuable skill to acquire. The truth is out there. Go find it.